# NUXT JS - Setting dynamic env vars and passing them to Axios, depending on localhost, dev or prod environment

Tags: nuxt.js

I am trying to set up environment variables for the API url, for example

DEV_API=dev.api.com
PROD_API=api.com

and trying to set those in the nuxt.config.js so that I can use them in the services.js file in the axios isntance, depending on the local, dev or live server. I can't seem to understand how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Open your nuxt.config.js file

and register a property env like this

```
export default{
 env:{
  DEV_API:'dev.api.com',
  PROD_API:'api.com'
 },
 css:[],
 plugins:[]
 ...other code continues here...
}
```

then in your page you can access env via "context.env" or "process.env"
e.x.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h4>dev: {{dev_api}}</h4>
    <h4>dev2: {{dev_api2}}</h4>
  </div>
</template>
export default{
   //server side
   async asyncData(context){
      return {
        dev_api: context.env.DEV_API,
        prod_api: context.env.PROD_API
      }
   },
   data(){
      return {
         dev_api2: process.env.DEV_API,
         prod_api2: process.env.PROD_API
      }
    }
 }
```